# Handling logging into SPA application: getting user info, managing claims

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, openiddict

**Context:**

I've implemented OpenIddict in my application, basing on [GitHub readme](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core#getting-started). I currently use TokenEndpoint to log user in.

```
services.AddOpenIddict<ApplicationUser, UsersDbContext>().EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/Account/Login")
```

Although calling `/api/Account/Info` works and it returns token in response, I need to get some basic data about logged in user (username, email, account type). Response from token endpoint doesn't provide that.

I've found something like UserinfoEndpoint:

```
.EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/api/Account/Info")
```

But what I see after in http response is:

```
{
  "sub": "ea2248b4-a[...]70757de60fd",
  "iss": "http://localhost:59381/"
}
```

This should return me some `Claims`. As it doesn't return anything, I assume that no `Identity Claims` were created during token generation.

**What I need to know in a nutshell:**

1. Is using Token Endpoint correct way to log in user?
2. Do I need to generate Claims by myself?
3. Can I control Claims by myself and how?
4. How to make some Claims visible through UserInfoEndpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is using Token Endpoint correct way to log in user?

Yep.

> Do I need to generate Claims by myself?

The userinfo endpoint simply exposes the tokens stored in the access token (which is something that may change in the future).

> Can I control Claims by myself and how?
>   How to make some Claims visible through UserInfoEndpoint?

To allow the userinfo endpoint to return more claims, you'll have to request more scopes. Read http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims for more information.

In a future version, we may allow you to return custom claims, but it's not currently supported.

Comment: It's not clear to me how to "request more scopes". Page that you've linked to says that scope request should look like: "scope=openid profile email phone". But what is that? Header? Body of request? How am I supposed to use it?

Comment: You're supposed to send it with the other token request parameters, in the request body (encoded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Comment: I'm asking because, as you see, nothing really changed

Comment: I said token request, not userinfo request.